# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 65

Tags: c#, sql, database, publish

I wanted to change the sqlconnection from `properties.default` to a generic destionation, so it can be published and working from another pc. The problem is I'm getting this error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 65.

There's the connectionstring tried: (not working)

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LocalDB\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydatabase.mdf;Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
```

This data source was taken from a table which is working perfectly.

There's the working connectionstring:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(system32.Properties.Settings.Default.mydatabaseConnectionString);
```

Comment: Using a [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) might make it more transparent ...

Comment: You appear to have an unescaped backslash at `\mydatabase.mdf`.

Comment: @Iridium, you the MVP! Worked.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I will get documented, thanks a lot for the response!